# Search in rails/mongodb with found record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I've got a search form where i search for a name in Scans. If the name (its unique) is found, it checks for possible records that contain this name's code.

scan model contains:

```
  def self.search(search)
    where(name: /#{search}/i)
  end

  def self.search_by_code(search)
    where(code: /#{search}/i)
  end
```

scan controller:

```
  def search    
    respond_to do |format|
      # format.html {
      #   @scans = Scan.search(params[:search])
      #   render html: @scans
      # }
      format.json { 
        @original = Scan.search(params[:search])
        if @original
          @scans = Scan.search_by_code(@original.code)
          render json: @scans
        else
          render json: "no"
        end
        }
    end
  end
```

What am I doing wrong? How to do this properly?

The idea is to get:

```
[
{"code":"29304","name":"Albert"}, 
{"code":"23094","name":"Jackie"},
{"code":"29304","name":"Nora"}
]
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your view here

Comment: @CodeMaster123, currently this is just raw output (everything). Didnt make a view yet for json. Do you mean this? Just to be sure, ive added the goal view (not made yet)

Comment: What `search` method returns - array or single record?  What each method returns when nothing found?  nil or empty array?  If empty array - you should check like `@found.empty?`.  Also, consider preserving your regular expression from malicious input (with to_regexp gem or some similar if you really need a regex there).

Comment: thanks @taro, i'll check out that gem. search method returns an array. Ill have to add errors, good point. But, do you know why its not working at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no mongodb experience, I advise you to play with it in a rails console.

Comment: bummer :) thanks though!